# Inserting hyphenation file into \babelhyphenation

Tags: babel, expansion, hyphenation, input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{english.yp}
    hom-ony-mous
    gene-ral-ly
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\babelhyphenation[british]{\@@input english.yp }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
spinach.
\end{document}
```

It appears that latex expects to see the closing `}` inside the file. And if I delete the space after `yp`, it thinks the bracket is part of the filename ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can protect the definition from premature expansion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{english.yp}
    hom-ony-mous
    gene-ral-ly
\end{filecontents*}

\showhyphens{homonymous}
\makeatletter
{\everyeof{\noexpand}\xdef\tmp{\@@input english.yp }}
\babelhyphenation[british]{\tmp}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\showhyphens{homonymous}% to show new hyphens in force
spinach.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! this does compile with latex, but not with lualatex, which returns `! File ended while scanning text of \hyphenation.
<inserted text>
}
l.2 \select@language{british}

?
`

Comment: @Lawrence hmph, try now:-)

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't try to use \input inside such command arguments. Better first read the file and then use it. Eg.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hyphenationfromfile}{m}
  {
    \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { } { #1 }
    \exp_args:NV \hyphenation \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{filecontents*}{english.yp}
    hom-ony-mous
    gene-ral-ly
\end{filecontents*}

\hyphenationfromfile{english.yp}

\textwidth 3cm
\begin{document}
spinach. homonymous homonymous homonymous homonymous homonymous  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Ulrike's idea, here's a reimplementation of `\babelhyphenation` that accepts a *-variant which, instead of a list of words, inputs a file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{english.yp}
    hom-ony-mous
    gene-ral-ly
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{catchfile,letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\babel@babelhyphenation\babelhyphenation
\renewcommand{\babelhyphenation}{%
  \@ifstar\lawrence@babelhyphenation\babel@babelhyphenation
}
\newcommand\lawrence@babelhyphenation[2][\@empty]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\lawrence@hyphfile}{#2}{}%
  \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup
    \babel@babelhyphenation[\unexpanded{#1}]{\unexpanded\expandafter{\lawrence@hyphfile}}%
  }\x
}
\makeatother

%\babelhyphenation*[british]{english.yp}
%\babelhyphenation[british]{tree-munch}
\babelhyphenation*{english.yp}
\babelhyphenation{tree-munch}

\begin{document}

\showhyphens{homonymous generally treemunch}

\end{document}
```

If I use the commented lines

```
\babelhyphenation*[british]{english.yp}
\babelhyphenation[british]{tree-munch}
```

instead of the ones without the optional argument, the output is the same:

```
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 hom-ony-mous gene-rally tree-munch
```

Without calling `\babelhyphenation`, the output is

```
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 hom-onym-ous gen-er-ally tree-m-unch
```

Note that the hyphenation point `ral-ly` is not shown because `\righthyphenmin` is set to 3 for British English.